# Angular 2 Library config

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently I am trying to create my first Angular 2 library, a translate pipe. Right now I am trying to make the developer able to insert an object with translations into the module so the pipe can use it.

How can I insert some sort of config/object into my library so all my components, pipes and services can use it?

My library looks like:

index.ts

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TranslatePipe } from './translate.pipe';

export * from './translate.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        TranslatePipe
    ],
    exports: [
        TranslatePipe
    ]
})
export class TranslateModule
{
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders
    {
        return {
            ngModule: TranslateModule,
            providers: []
        };
    }
}
```

translate.pipe.ts

```
import { Injectable, PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'translate'
})

@Injectable()

export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform
{

    public translations: any = null;

    constructor ()
    {
        this.translations = {};
    }

    transform(key: string): string
    {
        let translation = key;

        if (key in this.translations) translation = this.translations[key];

        return translation;
    }
}
```

My testing project:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { TranslateModule } from 'translate-pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TranslateModule
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [
        TranslateModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just let the user pass a config object to the `forRoot()` method, then set it as a service

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const TRANSLATE_CONFIG = new InjectionToken();

export interface TranslateConfig {
  someProp?: string;
  anotherProp?: string;
}

export class TranslateModule {

  // config is optional. You can use configure default below
  static forRoot(config?: TranslateConfig) { // <========
    const conf = createConfig(config); // maybe set some defaults

    return {
      ngModule: TranslateModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: TRANSLATE_CONFIG, useValue: conf }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then wherever you need to inject the config, just do (in your pipe)

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateConfig, TRANSLATE_CONFIG } from './wherever';


constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATE_CONFIG) config: TranslateConfig) {}
```

The user would do

```
imports: [
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    someProp: someValue,
    anotherProp: anotherValue
  })
]
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering my question! I already thought I had to use this for root function. However I'm getting an error and warning. Error: `Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__.InjectionToken is not a constructor`. Warning: `export 'InjectionToken' was not found in '@angular/core'`. Maybe any idea why this error is thrown? Also I had to add a description to the constructor of InjectionToken, `new InjectionToken('blablalba')`.

Comment: If you're still using Angular 2.x, then you should use `OpaqueToken` instead. `InjectionToken` is added in Angular 4.x. When you use `OpaqueToken`, you should give it a unique name, e.g. `new OpaqueToken('translate.config')`

Comment: Also, you don't _have_ to use `InjectionToken`. You could make `TRANSLATE_CONFIG` a string if you wanted. It would still work.

Comment: i have implement the similar way it works fine in my local but when i deploy the app, config in the library i am receiving null, any thoughts ?

Comment: Excellent solution. One problem I see in it is adding code before the return object in `forRoot` function, this will result in an error when building the app with optimizer set to `true`