# How to use service inside import decorator for angular module config?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module, angular-library

I want to method in service for module config, but module is loaded from decorator, and service is not DI yet. How to use service inside load module?

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43683182/5989987) answer for example

For example method in service is a Observeable, here is the config

```js
export interface TranslateConfig {
  someProp?: string;
  anotherProp?: string;
  observeableProp?: Observeable<string>
}
```

And then to load module in app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      someProp: someValue,
      anotherProp: anotherValue,
      observeableProp: (method from service)
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule{
  ...
}
```

I want to use service inside decorator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved.
There is no way to use service inside decorator.

To solve this issue, create new service inside ConfigurableModule.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthSerivce{

  constructor() { }

  private authFunction: Observable<string>;
}
```

In your app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ConfigurableModule.forRoot({
      YOUR CONFIG HERE
    }),
  ],
...
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private configurableModuleAuthService: ConfigurableModuleAuthService
  ) {
    configurableModuleAuthService.authFunction = of("YOUR AUTHENTICATION OBSERVABLE METHOD HERE");
  }
}
```

To use this service inside ConfigurableModule, it is the same with normal DI service